# glColorPointer iOS Open GL ES not working?

Tags: ios, cocoa, opengl-es

I am drawing a simple GL_LINE_LOOP on a black background. No matter what I do with the glColorPointer and colors[] array I can't make the lines any other color than white. What am I doing wrong?
I'm relatively new to open gl for iPhone and haven't found an answer on Google or here for my problem so I really appreciate any answers.

```
//glPushMatrix();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
static const GLubyte colors[] = {  
    255,   0,   255, 255,
    255,   0,   255, 255,
    255,   0,   255, 255
};
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState (GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, colors);
glLineWidth(5.0);
GLfloat vertices[] = { -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0 };
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 3);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: The 2 following lines are now before defining the colors[] array but I am still not getting a color.                glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling texturing...

```
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
```

Comment: I've added those lines before declaring my color[] array but still no luck - the lines are still white. Any other ideas? - thanks

Comment: Hmm still no luck - I now have this before my colors[] declaration:glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE,GL_ZERO);

Comment: The only other idea I have is to make sure that the texture coord array is disabled, glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); Is there any errors generated after the glDrawArrays Call? printf("%d\n",glGetError());

Comment: Thanks for your help ... a combination of disabling the Textures and turning off a white light gives me purple lines.